# Use cookie from ajax post request in cross subsequent ajax get request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cookies

This is my first week using javascript and am trying to access an api which requires authentication via a post request. The post work fine but I can't figure out how to send the cookie with the get request.

EDIT2:

I changed the success function to:

```
success: function(data, status, xhr);
```

following the documentation a bit closer. From console.log(data, status, xhr) the following is returned:

Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "{"value":{"publisher":{"active":"1","publisher_id":"######"}}}", responseJSON: Object, status: 201, statusText: "Created"}

Maybe that clarifies things for someone out there?

Here is my code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "https://publisher-api.com/1.0/Publisher/Login", 
                type:"POST",
                data: {"username":"######","password":"@@@@@@"}, 
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                }
            });
            $.ajax({
                url: "https://publisher-api.com/1.0/Publisher(######)/Channels/RevenueReport",
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://publisher-api.com/1.0/Publisher(######)/Channels/RevenueReport",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: It throws the following error: XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://publisher-api.com/1.0/Publisher(######)/Channels/RevenueReport. A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is true. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: The credentials must be enabled on your server side as well, but it seems they are not enabled (`*` is used for `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header) - are you sure that your API can be used that way?

Comment: I am not sure but will find out, is there another common way of using/accessing the api that I could try or should I just make sure that the credentials are enabled on the server side first?

Comment: Well, I am not sure how your API exactly works, but could you try to remove `xhrFields` property and change `dataType` to `jsonp`.

Comment: Well, you should contact them and ask if there's a way to process request with `setCredentials` set to true.

Comment: This documentation looks like it's promising, but I'm not sure how to implement it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTTP_access_control#Requests_with_credentials

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the ajax calls are asynchronous, so as the first one is still waiting for a response, the second one is already firing off as well.

If I understand what you want to do (get the cookie with the post, and then use the cookie in the get), you'll want to nest the ajax calls. So

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "https://publisher-api.com/1.0/Publisher/Login", 
                type:"POST",
                data: {"username":"######","password":"@@@@@@"}, 
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(response) {
                  $.ajax({
                    url: "https://publisher-api.com/1.0/Publisher("+ response.cookie +")/Channels/RevenueReport",
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                  });
                }
            });

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

assuming that the response from the first ajax call contains the cookie.

Comment: Publisher(######) in the URL is the account number which is returned from the post request but I'm not sure about how the cookie is returned

Comment: nesting the call did not seem to help.